# What's this connector type?

Tags: hardware

Does anybody know this kind of connector? It is used as a diagnostic connector on diesel engines. Inner diameter 15mm, outer 19mm.

[image: Female socket]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an industrial type `ITT Cannon KPT01E12-10S`, like this one:

https://www.westfloridacomponents.com/C069APP10/KPT01E12-10S+10+Pos.+Circular+Connector+Receptacle+ITT+Cannon.html

This connector is used for CAN bus communication, which can be used for diagnostics, among other applications.